# Does CMake support macro or function overloading?

Tags: cmake, macros, overloading

I am trying to achieve something as follows:

```
macro(OVERLOAD_TEST par1 par2)
  message ("Macro with two arguments")
endmacro()

macro(OVERLOAD_TEST par1 par2 par3)
  message ("Macro with three arguments")
endmacro()
```

And, called the macro like this:

```
OVERLOAD_TEST("A" "B" "C")
OVERLOAD_TEST("A" "B")
```

But got the following error:

```
Macro with three arguments
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:59 (OVERLOAD_TEST):
  OVERLOAD_TEST Macro invoked with incorrect arguments for macro named:
  OVERLOAD_TEST
```

Should I use the optional argument support feature of CMake instead and have only one macro?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no: CMake does not have macro or function overloading features like you have shown in your imaginary example. Defining a macro or function multiple times will just lead to the last definition being used regardless of what directory scope that last definition was made at, since function and macro definitions themselves are not scoped.

But you can just write the "overloads" in one single macro definition by switching based on the number and qualities of the passed arguments. For example, in the example you showed, your overloads have different numbers of arguments, so you can distinguish such varying calls by the value of `${ARGC}` (see [the macro argument docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html#arguments) and [the function argument docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html#arguments)).

If you have "overloads" with the same number of arguments, I'd recommend switching to parsing with named parameters (see [the `cmake_parse_arguments` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html), which helps with that).

If you don't want to use named parameters, then you can look at doing pattern-based matching to distinguish between overload signatures if possible (see [the `string` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html) and its various subcommands).